# No such file or directory - ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to read the contents of the file from a local disk as follows :

```
content = File.read("C:\abc.rb","r")
```

when I execute the rb file I get an exception as Error: No such file or directory .What am I missing in this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a double quoted string, "\a" is a non-printable bel character.  Similar to how "\n" is a newline. (I think these originate from C)

You don't have a file with name "C:<BEL>bc.rb" which is why you get the error.

To fix, use single quotes, where these interpolations don't happen:

```
content = File.read('C:\abc.rb')
```

Comment: The simplest way though is to use forward slashes everywhere in paths. Ruby understands that. `File.read("C:/abc.rb","r")`

Comment: I used your line of code ...but still I get the error : No such file or directory abc.rb even though I can see the file being present

Comment: Not sure then :( it works for me although I did have to remove the invalid second argument when I came to test it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all:

Try using:

```
Dir.glob(".")
```

To see what's in the directory (and therefore what directory it's looking at).

```
open("C:/abc.rb", "rb") { |io| a = a + io.read }
```

**EDIT: Unless you're concatenating files together, you could write it as:**

```
data = File.open("C:/abc.rb", "rb") { |io| io.read }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
content = File.read("C:\/abc.rb","r")
```

Comment: Don't you mean `"C:\\abc.rb"` or `"C:/abc.rb"`? Escaping a slash is okay but a bit misleading.